# How to Decide InputStream Encoding?

Tags: java, android

My objective is to download an xml feed into an InputStream, then convert it to a String so that if may be used with XmlPullParser.

I convert the InputStream into a String like this:

```
InputStream input_stream = connection.getInputStream();
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input_stream,"UTF-8"));
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}
```

Here's the problem, some XML feeds define specific encoding. Take this one for example:
http://voxinox.ch/podcasts/valdo/feed.xml

If I use a default of "UTF-8" encoding some characters from the feed look like a black rhombus shape with a question mark in it. If I use the encoding specified in the xml header it works (iso-8859-1), not a surprise.

The thing is how do I decide what encoding to use before I start reading the input stream which contains encoding specifications? Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: In an XML you usually get meta information up front like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>. You should use the encoding-value from the meta information for correct encoding .In example voxinox.ch/podcasts/valdo/feed.xml is the encoding <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>

Comment: Agreed, I'm looking for a way to decode my inputStream with the encoding value, however I need to specify the encoding before accessing the inputStream, a bit of a chicken and egg situation.

Comment: There is clearly the first egg. For XML inputstream <?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?> is equal for all kind of encoding. Read tag encoding first and than read all again with right encoding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example how i get encoding from XML inputstream

```
FileInputStream finput = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                    String encoding = getInputEncoding(finput);
                    Log.d("Encoding: ", "> " + encoding);


public String getInputEncoding(FileInputStream finput){
      String encoding = "";
      if(finput!=null){

          try{
          BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(finput));
          String getline = "";
          getline = myReader.readLine();
          myReader.close();
          Log.d("Line: ", "> " + getline);

            String[] separated = getline.split("encoding=\"");
            String encoding1 = separated[1];
            String[] separated2 = encoding1.split("\"");
            encoding = separated2[0];

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }

      }
      return encoding;
    }
```